# Tkinter button doesn't work in exe file but do when the script is executed

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm new on this forum and on Tkinter and I need your help.
I'm trying to create a GUI. My program works perfectly when I run the file with Python 2.7, but one of the button doesn't work when I create an exe file thanks to pyinstaller.

My program is pretty simple : I select a camera in the list of the available ones, click on the "Display" button and the video frame from the selected camera should be displayed in a new window, thanks to opencv. The 'quit' button is here to quit the app.

When I create an executable file thanks to pyinstaller, the window is displayed, I can select a camera, but the 'Display' button doesn't work. I really do not understand why, and no error message is displayed.

Thanks a lot for your help

```
import cv2 
from Tkinter import *



class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk() 
        self.root.title("Rééducation posturale")
        self.root.config(background="#FA8066")

        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


        self.boutonquitter=Button(self.root,text='Quit',font=("Helvetica", 10),command=self.Quitapp)
        self.boutonquitter.pack()
        self.boutonquitter.grid(row=1, column=1)



        camIndices=self.detectNumCameras()
        camIndex = []
        for n in xrange(camIndices):
            camIndex.append(n) 

        # LIST OF AVAILABLE CAMERA
        Label(self.root, text="Camera",font=("Helvetica", 10), bg="#ECA7A6").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.cameraIndex = StringVar(self.root)
        self.cameraIndex.set("Choose camera")
        dropCamera = apply(OptionMenu, (self.root, self.cameraIndex) + tuple(camIndex))
        dropCamera.grid(row=0, column=1)  

        #CLICK TO DISPLAY
        self.bouton = Button(self.root, text="Display", font=("Helvetica", 10), command=self.checkCamera)
        self.bouton.pack()
        self.bouton.grid(row=1, column=0) 

        imageFrame = Frame(self.root, width=600, height=400)
        self.display = Label(imageFrame)
        self.root.mainloop()


    # DETECT CAMERAS
    def detectNumCameras(self):
        ind = 0
        while True:
            vc = cv2.VideoCapture(ind)
            if (vc.isOpened()):
                ind += 1
                vc.release()
            else:
                break
        return(ind)



    def checkCamera(self):
        try:
            self.cam.release()
        except:
            pass
        self.cam=cv2.VideoCapture(int(self.cameraIndex.get()))
        _,frame=self.cam.read()
        self.display.after(10,self.show_frame)


    #CLOSE THE APP
    def Quitapp(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    #DISPLAY FRAME IN A NEW WINDOW
    def show_frame(self):
        ret,frame = self.cam.read()

        if ret is True:        
            cv2.imshow('Video',frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            self.display.after(10, self.show_frame)

Gui()
```

Edit: I've tried with py2exe and have uninstalled python 2.7 to install python 3.6 and I still have the same problem ... My code is also simpler:

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk() 
        width, height = 800, 600
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        self.cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

        self.root.title("Test")

        #CLICK TO DISPLAY
        self.bouton = tk.Button(self.root, text="Display", font=("Helvetica", 10), command=self.CreateNewWindow)
        self.bouton.pack()

        self.boutonquitter=tk.Button(self.root,text='Quit',font=("Helvetica", 10),command=self.Quitapp)
        self.boutonquitter.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


    def CreateNewWindow(self):
        self.top = tk.Toplevel()
        self.top.title("window")
        self.lmain = tk.Label(self.top)
        self.lmain.pack()
        self.lmain.after(10, self.show_frame)


    #CLOSE THE APP
    def Quitapp(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    #DISPLAY FRAME IN A NEW WINDOW
    def show_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.cam.read()
        if ret is True:
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            self.lmain.imgtk = imgtk
            self.lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
            self.lmain.after(10, self.show_frame)


Gui()
```

I've attached the screenshots when I run the script in python and when I run the .exe
[python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pidgx.gif)
[exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz8re.gif)

Comment: Is this the full code (because there are quite a few bugs just running it in IDLE)

Comment: Yes it is. Really? What are the bugs? (I don't have any on my computer)

Comment: Unless they removed this method in Python 3, there is no `apply` method (`dropCamera = apply(OptionMenu, (self.root, self.cameraIndex) + tuple(camIndex))`)

Comment: I've tried to change with

choices={int(camIndex[i]) for i in range(len(camIndex))}
menu = OptionMenu(self.root, self.cameraIndex, *choices)
menu.grid(row =0, column =1)'

but I still have the same problem (.py works but .exe doesn't)

Comment: You could try `py2exe` instead but I'm not sure what difference this makes (I'm not even sure if its compatible with 2.7)